# Probability students get excellent marks

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

In the Department of Accounting, 45% of the students who attend the course of Statistics are freshmen, 35% are second-year students and the rest are third-year students and above. According to data from the Department, 15% of the first-year students who attend the course receive excellent marks, 25% of the second-year students receive excellent marks, while 30% of the third-year students and above receive excellent marks.

a) What is the probability that a student (regardless of the year of study) got an excellent grade?

b) If he got excellent, then what is the probability of being a second-year student?

c) If he didn't get excellent, then what is the probability of being a second-year student?

$$$$

a) We have that :

- $P(\text{1-Year})=45\%$
- $P(\text{2-Year})=35\%$
- $P(\text{3-Year})=(100-45-35)\%=20\%$
- $P(\text{1-Year}\cap \text{excellent})=15\%$
- $P(\text{2-Year}\cap \text{excellent})=25\%$
- $P(\text{3-Year}\cap \text{excellent})=30\%$

Is that correct so far?

The probability that a student (regardless of the year of study) got an excellent grade is equal to \begin{align*}P(\text{excellent})&=P(\text{1-Year}\cap \text{excellent})+P(\text{2-Year}\cap \text{excellent})+P(\text{3-Year}\cap \text{excellent})\\ & =15\%+25\%+30\%\\ & =70\%\end{align*}
Is that correct?

b) If he got excellent, then the probability of being a second-year student is equal to $$P(\text{2-Year}\mid \text{excellent})=\frac{P(\text{2-Year}\cap \text{excellent})}{P(\text{excellent})}=\frac{25\%}{70\%}=35.71\%$$
Is that correct?

c) If he didn't get excellent, then the probability of being a second-year student is equal to $$P(\text{2-Year}\mid \text{excellent}^c)=\frac{P(\text{2-Year}\cap \text{excellent}^c)}{P(\text{excellent}^c)}=\frac{P(\text{2-Year}\cap \text{excellent}^c)}{100\%-70\%}=\frac{P(\text{2-Year}\cap \text{excellent}^c)}{30\%}$$
Is that correct so far? How can we calculate the probability $P(\text{2-Year}\cap \text{excellent}^c)$ ?

Comment: Your answer looks fine to me. For the last one, you know $P(\text{2-Year}\cap \text{excellent})$ then, what about $P(\text{2-Year}\cap \text{excellent}^c)$ ?

Comment: Is the following correct? $$P(\text{2-Year}\cap \text{excellent}^c)=P(\text{2-Year})-P(\text{2-Year}\cap \text{excellent})=35\%-25\%=10\%$$ Then \begin{align*}P(\text{2-Year}\mid \text{excellent}^c)&=\frac{P(\text{2-Year}\cap \text{excellent}^c)}{P(\text{excellent}^c)}\\ & =\frac{P(\text{2-Year}\cap \text{excellent}^c)}{100\%-70\%}\\ & =\frac{10\%}{30\%}\\ & =33.33\%\end{align*} @Atmos

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: @MaryStar you have a mistake in $(a)$ as you are adding probability of being Excellent given first year, second year or third+ year without multiplying by the probability of a student being a first year, a second year or a third+ year student. See my answer. ($b$) and ($c$) follow from there.

Comment: P(excellent) should be less than 30% certainly. If in ALL years 30% received excellent marks, then the answer would be 30%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \small\begin{aligned}  
P(Y1) &=45\% \\  
P(Y2) &= 35\% \\  
P(Y3) &=20\% \\  
\end{aligned}$

$\small\begin{aligned}
P(E~|Y1) &=15\% \\  
P(E~|Y2) &= 25\% \\  
P(E~|Y3) &=30\% \\  
\end{aligned}$

For $(a)$,
$ \small P(E) = P(E~|Y1) ~P(Y1) + P(E~|Y2) ~P(Y2) + P(E~|Y3) ~P(Y3)$
$ \small  = 0.15 \times 0.45 + 0.25 \times 0.35 + 0.30 \times 0.20$
$ = 0.215 ~ $ or $ ~ 21.5 \%$

For $(b)$, note that $ \small P(Y2|E) = \cfrac{P(E|Y2) ~P(Y2)}{P(E)}$

For $(c)$, first find $ \small P(E^c) = 1 - P(E), P(E^c|Y2) = 1 - P(E|Y2)$ and then using the same formula as $(b)$, you can find $ \small P(Y2|E^c)$.

Comment: At (b) we have $$\small P(Y2|E) = \cfrac{P(E|Y2) ~P(Y2)}{P(E)}=\frac{0.25\cdot 0.35}{0.215}=\frac{35}{86}\approx 40,70\%$$ At (c) we have $P(E^c)=1-P(E)=0.785$, $P(E^c\mid Y2)=1-P(E\mid Y2)=0.75$ and so $$P(Y2\mid E^c)=\frac{P(E^c\mid Y2)\cdot P(Y2)}{P(E^c)}=\frac{0.75\cdot 0.35}{0.785}=\frac{105}{314}\approx 33,44\%$$ Is everything correct?

Comment: @MaryStar yes everything is correct now

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! :-) Could you take a look at my other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4244637/statistical-values-about-stock-in-different-years ? @MathLover